# What is the difference between "Kernel messages" and "Messages from the init system and the system logger"

Tags: linux, boot, qemu, linux-kernel, grub

In this [blog](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html), it gives a Recommended serial kernel parameters, PCs with video card.

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8
```

It says `Kernel messages will appear on both the first virtual terminal and the serial port. Messages from the init system and the system logger will appear only on the first serial port.`

As it says before `When multiple consoles are listed output is sent to all consoles and input is taken from the last listed console`, Isn't this contradictory? What is the difference between "Kernel messages" and "Messages from the init system and the system logger" ?

I want to know:

1. Why is this ?
   Update: Why do not get the same output between multiple terminals ?
2. Where `Messages from the init system and the system logger` go ?
3. What kind of devices are virtual consoles such as ttyx redirected to, and why I can only see them in the graphical interface of qemu, like `Debian GNU/Linux 10 mindebian tty1` ?

Update:
In normal we will get message from kernel and rootfs,
message from kernel start with a timestamp [kernel message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA9Gt.png),
message from init/rootfs start with a OK [rootfs message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf0sN.png).
When I use this boot arguments in the blog, exactly as it described: I will only get kernel message from qemu graphic window.

Comment: The information on the page you were reading is almost 20 years old. And I'm pretty sure it's wrong and that all messages appear on both specified consoles today.

Comment: I tried the parameters he gave and they were correct, so I came to ask everyone, maybe I didn’t describe accurately enough, so I added some pictures in the question.

Comment: I can confirm that using `console=tty0 console=ttyS0` will, indeed, make some messages appear only inside one of the consoles. I'm testing using qemu and the serial console (ttyS0) seems to receive all messages, while tty0 only receives a couple of them.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180441) may be... the answer. Apparently the last console you list is the one that will be used as `/dev/console` and, maybe, the messages we are not seeing are the ones being printed to `/dev/console` and because of that they are only showing in the last console defined in the kernel command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking several questions.

> Isn't this contradictory?

Personally, I don't see a contradiction. EDIT: I didn't read this correctly. You are right, this is a contradiction. I am not 100% sure, but I believe all console messages should go to all configured consoles.

> What is the difference between "Kernel messages" and "Messages from the init system and the system logger" ?

Kernel messages are generated by the kernel. Messages from the init system are generated by the processes that are involved in starting your Linux distro. Messages from the system logger are generated by applications on the running system that send their messages to the system logger. There is some overlap, e.g. the system logger may also log kernel messages.

> Why is this?

I don't understand what you mean by "this".

> Where Messages from the init system and the system logger go ?

The system logger distributes them to various log files depending on its configuration. This is made more complex by many distros running two system loggers nowadays, namely *journald* and *rsyslogd*. The init system that is mostly used these days, *systemd*, uses *journald* to log init messages.

> What kind of devices are virtual consoles such as ttyx redirected to, and why I can only see them in the graphical interface of qemu

Linux implements a console on the PC's graphics screen. This is why the non-serial console can only be seen on the
graphical interface. In fact, the kernel implements several virtual screens named tty1, tty2 etc. Use the `chvt` command or the ALT-Fx key combination to select the which screen is displayed (where x is the screen number).

For more information, search the internet for *linux virtual console* or similar, and study *journald* and *rsyslogd* as well as *systemd*, the prevalent init system on Linux servers these days.